# interop.adodb update in VB.net to Version 6.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, adodb

I am trying to build an old VB.net that was last built in VS2008. When I do it errors with

Error   33  Reference required to assembly 'Interop.ADODB, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type 'ADODB.ConnectModeEnum'. Add one to your project.

When I try to add V6.0 I get ambiguous references apparently because Interop.ADODB is still in the solution, and I can see it in the Object Browser. I do not know how to replace the old version or exactly where to add the Version 6.0.

I also have both an Interop.ADODB and a ADODB in the Object Browser and do not understand the difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Fully qualify the object. That should remove the ambiguity. You must have 2 libraries imported that have the same type.

Comment: Thank you Mary. That makes sense. I just do not know how or where to fully qualify it.

Comment: Try to remove any data related imports except what you are using. Perhaps just adding ADODB to the object type will do it. `ADODB.Connection`